# Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $\lim s_n = L$. Give a formal proof that $\lim\sqrt {s_n}$ exists.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I understand that we have to show for $L=0$ and $L\gt0$. But I am really stuck in how to do this using an $\epsilon-N$ proof, particularly for the case $L\gt0$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For $L>0$,
$$
\Bigl|\sqrt{s_n}-\sqrt L\Bigr|
=\biggl|\frac{(\sqrt{s_n}-\sqrt L)(\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt L)}{\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt L}\biggr|
=\frac{|s_n-L|}{\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt L}
\le\frac{|s_n-L|}{\sqrt L}.
$$
Since $s_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty$, $|s_n-L|$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**

$$x\longmapsto \sqrt x$$
is continuous on $[0,+\infty [$.

**Hint 2**

If you don't like the first argument,
$$|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|=\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}.$$
If $L>0$, using the fact that $s_n\to L$, you can find an upper bound of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt{L}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for all $L\geq0$:

Looking at the graph of $t\mapsto\sqrt{t}$ $(t\geq0)$ we see that for given distance $|y-x|$ the difference $\bigl|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}\bigr|$ is largest when the smaller of $x$ and $y$ is $\>=0$. In this case this difference is simply $=\sqrt{|y-x|}$. This implies that in general
$$\bigl|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}\bigr|\leq\sqrt{|y-x|}\qquad (x, \>y\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
We now can argue as follows: Given an $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N$ such that $|s_n-L|<\epsilon^2$ for all $n>N$. From $(1)$ it now follows that
$$\bigl|\sqrt{s_n}-\sqrt{L}\bigr|<\epsilon\qquad(n>N)\ .$$